# Spring Boot: How to inject server.contextPath from application.properties into MockServletContext

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox, contextpath

In application.properties I configured `server.contextPath=/app-service`.

Unfortunately, this values is not present in the test context:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class, SwaggerConfig.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class Swagger2MarkupTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.context.getServletContext().getContextPath(); // null
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }
}
```

I need the contextPath for the Swagger Docket which uses per default 
 `springfox.documentation.spring.web.paths.RelativePathProvider` which determines the contextPath by

```
  @Override
  protected String applicationPath() {
    return isNullOrEmpty(servletContext.getContextPath()) ? ROOT : servletContext.getContextPath();
  }
```

It is all about the RelativePathProvider which gets called much earlier than the unit test. It is not about injecting the contextPath into the unit test itself since it is to late as the RelativePathProvider already called `servletContext.getContextPath()` for the SwaggerConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that in several ways, here are two of them:

1. Inject spring `Environment` and get the property value:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class, SwaggerConfig.class })
   @WebAppConfiguration
   public class Swagger2MarkupTest {

       @Autowired
       private WebApplicationContext context;

       @Autowired
       private Environment environment;

       private MockMvc mockMvc;

       @Before
       public void setUp() {
           environment.getProperty("server.contextPath"); // should return /app-service
           this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inject it using `@Value`:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class, SwaggerConfig.class })
   @WebAppConfiguration
   public class Swagger2MarkupTest {

       @Autowired
       private WebApplicationContext context;

       @Value("server.contextPath")
       private String contextPath; // should populate with /app-service

       private MockMvc mockMvc;

       @Before
       public void setUp() {
           this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I know, but that's not what I was looking for. I don't want to get the contextPath in the UnitTest, I want it in the ServletContext (before the unit test started) so that RelativePathProvider gets it via servletContext.getContextPath()

Comment: Can you try to use `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`: `@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class, SwaggerConfig.class }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and see if changing to `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` also change to the behavior you expect? In general springfox should be aligned with the configuration and properties you use as it is a spring based module.

Comment: UnitTest does not start at all: org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [....Swagger2MarkupTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.